# How to match a line which should not contain a word after a matched word

Tags: regex

1) /abs/2-bhk-property-for-sale-in-builders-apartments-bang123asdxc/38070127?page=509

2) /vjr-apartments/private-k3zs0gdf

3) /dolphin-jasmine-apartments-navimumbai-approvals/psddp-3qfci22i

4) /kanaka-lakshmi-apartments-andra/private-67mwcdbe

What is the regex expression to match strings with 'apartment' but should not match 'private'?
i.e Should match 1) and 3) but not 2) and 4)

I wrote this regex `.*?(-)(apartments)(?!\/private).*` but it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
-apartments(?!.*?/private)
```

`(?!.*?/private)` is negative lookahead that will fail the match if `/private` string comes after `-apartments`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zI6fO0/1)

In some languages `/` needs to be escaped so use:

```
/-apartments(?!.*?\/private)/
```

Comment: thanks alot it works fine.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This matches the line.

```
.*apartments(?!.*/private).*
```